# Ожидание загрузки изображения в цикле для ротации изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Для одного функционала требуется сделать ротатор изображений, но не по обычному таймауту, а по таймауту после загрузки и показа изображения, т.е. этакий показ превью видео из кучи мини скриншотов видео, с таймаутом где то в 100 мс.

Проблема заключается в том что мне не удаётся заставить браузер сначала загрузить изображение, а потом показать его, и только после этого начинат отсчёт таймаута.
Проблема усугубляется что используется Lazy Load XT 1.1.0.

HTML изображения выглядит так:

```
<img src="URL" data-src="URL"
   data-images="изображение1|изображение2|изображение3|изображение4|изображение5|и т.д."
   data-timeout="опционально, по умолчанию 0.1">
```

Таких изображений множество, и у всех свои атрибуты, работать они должны соответственно так же независимо друг от друга.

1. При наведении указателя на изображение начинаем загрузку первого изображения из data-images.
2. После того как изображение успешно загружено, добавляем к img атрибут data-images_original с содержимым оригинального src и меняем img src на адрес полученного изображения. Если загрузка изображения завершилось неудачей, пробуем ещё 3 раза и переходим к следующему.
3. Начинаем отсчёт таймера, после окончания времени таймера, повторяем пункт №2 и пункт №3 (рекурсия).
4. Когда все изображения уже были показаны, начинаем показ с первого изображения из data-images по кругу.

Почему img.onload = function не дожидается исполнения кода внутри, и позволяет циклу исполняться дальше?

```js
$("[data-images]").on('mouseover mouseout', function(data) {
  if (data.type == "mouseover") {
    $(this).attr("data-images_original", $(this).attr("src"));
    images_data = $(this).attr("data-images");
    images = images_data.split('|');
    images_counter = images.length;
    timeout = 1000;

    for (for_counter = 1; for_counter < images_counter; for_counter++) {
      image_url = images[while_counter];
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        if (img.width == 0) {} else {
          // $(this).attr("src", image_url);
        }
      };
      img.onerror = function() {};
      img.src = image_url;
      $(this).attr("src", image_url);
    }
  } else if (data.type == "mouseout") {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-images_original"));
  }
});
```

Comment: HTML изображения выглядит так:
img src="URL" data-src="URL" data-images="изображение1|изображение2|изображение3|изображение4|изображение5|и т.д." data-timeout="опционально, по умолчанию 0.1"

Answer (score 0):

> Почему img.onload = function не дожидается исполнения кода внутри, и позволяет циклу исполняться дальше?

Потому что было бы плохо, если бы скрипт завис из-за долгой загрузки или ошибки. Поэтому onload выполняется асинхронно: цикл не будет ждать загрузки изображения, а выполнится практически моментально. А onload будет спокойно ждать, сработает после заргузки изображения... когда цикл давно уже будет завершен.

---

100ms слишком быстро, невозможно там что-то разглядеть) А вам нужна функция, которая будет вызывать сама себя после onload:

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

Array.from(test).forEach(function(img){
  let frameTimeout = null;
  
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    let imgs = this.dataset.images.split("|");    
    let i = 0;
    
    recursiveLoad();
    
    function recursiveLoad(){
      img.src = "https://gyazo.com/" + imgs[i] + '.png';
      
      img.onload = function(){
        i = (i == imgs.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
        frameTimeout = setTimeout(recursiveLoad, 1000);
      }
      // детали с onerror
    }
  });
  
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    clearTimeout(frameTimeout);
    img.src = ""; // default.png
  });
});
```

```css
img { width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<img class="test" data-images="f850be7e9fc91aa2c8cb844603ea1e10|c708f879e56f725318fafca74b9cbe7f|fe48322c44d1c214ee8d9ba49876a0da">

<img class="test" data-images="f850be7e9fc91aa2c8cb844603ea1e10|c708f879e56f725318fafca74b9cbe7f|fe48322c44d1c214ee8d9ba49876a0da">
```

Answer (score 0):

Создавать кучу `Image` буферов в циклах - совсем не требуется, если не хотим скачивать вообще все сразу.
Так как курсор один, он может быть только над одной картинкой единовременно. Значит, нужен всего один буферный элемент для всех, и только один таймер должен быть активен.

Пример:

```js
($ => {
  $(document).ready(previews); 

  function previews() {
    const buf = new Image(); 
    buf.cancel = function () { this.onload = void(0); }; 
    buf.load = function (src, cb) {
      this.cancel(); 
      this.onload = () => cb(src); 
      this.src = src; 
    }; 
    const nextSrc = el => {
      const images = $(el).data('images').split('|'), 
            curIdx = +$(el).data('idx'), 
            resetIdx = !isFinite(curIdx) || curIdx + 1 >= images.length, 
            nxtIdx = resetIdx ? 0 : curIdx + 1;
      $(el).data('idx', nxtIdx);  
      return images[nxtIdx]; 
    }; 
    $('[data-images]').on('mouseover', function () {
      buf.load(`https://picsum.photos/id/${nextSrc(this)}/1800`, src => {
        this.src = src; 
        this.previewTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          $(this).trigger('mouseover'); 
        }, (+$(this).data('timeout') || 0.1) * 1e3); 
      }); 
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
      clearTimeout(this.previewTimeout); 
      buf.cancel(); 
    }).each(function () {
      this.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${nextSrc(this)}/180`; 
    }); 
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
img { width: 180px; height: 180px; background: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<img src="" data-src="URL" data-images="1|2|3|4|5" data-timeout="0.5">
<img src="" data-src="URL" data-images="6|7|8|9|10" data-timeout="0.5">
<img src="" data-src="URL" data-images="11|12|13|14|15" data-timeout1="0.5">
```

Картинки прописал пожирнее, чтобы грузились не моментально.
Первый цикл переключения с прогрузками, в последующих уже используется кэш браузера (особенно заметно это будет на третьем элементе, с дефолтным интервалом 0,1с).

В реальном коде, помимо обработки ошибок, желательно: подгружать следующую превьюшку заранее (начиная сразу после переключения), и хранить массив ссылок из data-атрибута в объекте элемента (чтобы на каждом переключении не создавать этот массив заново).

Comment: Честно сказать я не до конца понимаю как работает ваш JS код, но он заменяет изображения без наведения указателя, т.е. сразу после загрузки страницы.
data-images="url|url|url|url|url" должен выглядеть, в шапке немного расплывчато написал.

Comment: @SKYNET74, не заменяет, а инициализирует первым изображением в списке (изначально `src` пуст. Если будет не пуст - то этого можно не делать).